# The operator + is undefined for the argument types

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to display a deck of cards for a JavaFX program but I keep getting the error in title. I had the same set up in a previous program and it ran fine. Now I keep getting the error in title.

```
package pickFourCards;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class PickFourCards extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Image card = new Image ("./image.card");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(card);

        ArrayList<Integer> deck = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 1; i < 52; i++)
            {
                deck.add(i);
            }//end for 

        HBox pane = new HBox(10);
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Button refresh = new Button("Refresh");
        //put okhandler class here
        pane.getChildren().addAll(refresh);
        //it's right at this line I get the error
        for(int h = 0; h < 4; h++)
        pane.getChildren().add(new ImageView((card) + (deck.get(h)) +      ".png"));
        //end h
        //this is the same set up in previous program too ^
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Excercise15_1");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
     }//start(Stage)

}//end class
```

Comment: Well you didn't have the exact same code working, certainly. You should look at the differences between that code and your broken code.

Comment: `+` is left associative. So the expression attempts to first evaluate `card + deck.get(h)`; i.e. tries to apply `+` to an `Image` and an `Integer`, which it can't do. You could do `card.toString() + deck.get(h) + ".png"`, or put parentheses around the last two arguments (forcing them to be evaluated first; they would evaluated to a `String`). But I'm not sure this is what you want anyway.